# Is there any limit on the number of wifi networks that can be detected by a general smartphone (iOS and Android phones)?

Tags: android, ios, android-wifi, smartphone, hotspot

I am trying to make a mobile application which needs to detect all the active hot spots around it and use the information for further processing. Note that I only need it to detect the hot spots and not connect to them.

Comment: There can be no limits. If the Wifi is in device range it should be detected.

Comment: My application needs to detect around 80-100 hot spots at a time. Will there be any problem?

Comment: See, its rare that someone has tested this kind of scenario. But, most probably there would not be any issue if Wifi networks are in range.